# Why isn't 6/ 5 being printed when average is less than 0.8

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program for helping me figure out my final grades but when the average is less than 0.8, 6/5 isn't being printed.

```
sum1 = 0

input_string = input("Enter decimal grade separated by commas for     Maths ")
list  = input_string.split(",")
for num in list:
    sum1 +=  float(num)
print("Average=", sum1/len(list))

average1= (sum1/len(list))/10

if average1 >= 0.8:
    print('7');
elif average1 >=0.68:
    print('6');
elif average1 >= 0.55:
    print('5');
else:
    print('not found')
```

Expected output of 0.69, 0.69 is

```
Average= 0.69
6
```

Actual output of 0.69, 0.69 is

```
Average= 0.69
not found
```

Comment: Well, `average=0.69`, you then managed `average1 = average/10` which makes `average1==0.069`, of course you're going to get not found.

Comment: You have an extra /10 at calculation of average1.

Comment: Don't redefine the python reserved keywords, list is a type, you should not use it for a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

You're dividing by 10 after calculating (and printing) the average. So when it prints `Average= 0.69`, it then tries to look up `0.069`, which is too small, so it says `not found`.